# How to set focus to Vue3 Typescript app to input element on Bootstrap modal when opened

Tags: typescript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

```
I'm trying to do what seems to be a simple and common thing, that is proving to be quite difficult. I simply need a specific text input element to be set to focus upon the modal dialog opening. Here is what I've tried:
```

**Use autofocus on the HTML element.**

```
<input placeholder="Enter search text" type="text" autofocus class="form-control" v-model="searchterm"/>
```

Does not focus , no errors ...

**Use v-focus on input element along with a directive.**

```
<input placeholder="Enter search text" type="text" v-focus class="form-control" v-model="searchterm"/>


<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent, PropType } from "@vue/runtime-core";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Crops-view",
  setup() {
  },
  directives: {
    focus: {
      mounted: (el) => {
        el.focus();
        console.log("focus set");
      },
    },
  props: { ...   ...},
});
</script>
```

This apparently does fire the routine, but does so at initial page load, not at modal dialog open. This obviously won't work if I have multiple dialog boxes, each with its own initial focus.

**Use watch to trigger a function upon change in dialog visibility**

```
<div
    class="modal fade m-3 p-3 justify-content-center"
    id="crops-modal"
    data-bs-backdrop="static"
    v-show="showCropsModal"
 
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="title text-center">Crops</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-2">
          <input
            placeholder="Enter search text"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="searchterm"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent, PropType, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Crops-view",
  setup() {
    const showCropsModal = true;
    const cropsearchinput = ref<HTMLInputElement>();
    return { showCropsModal, cropsearchinput};
  },
  watch: {
    showCropsModal(value) {
      if (value) {
        (cropsearchinput.value as HTMLElement).focus();
      }
    },
  },
  props: { ...   ...},
});
</script>
```

Does not compile . I got a lint error 'cropsearchinput' is not defined.

I directives, methods, watch, v-focus and autofocus.

Comment: To fix the compile error, use the Composition API's `watch()` inside `setup()` instead of the `watch` option.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone went to the same issue

here's my solution

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const modal = ref<boolean>(false)
const btn = ref<HTMLButtonElement>()

watch(modal, (newVal: boolean) => {
  if (newVal==true) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      btn.value!.focus()
    }, 100)
  }
})
</script>
```